# writing to model field in django / python

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to populate custom user profile fields with data from social networks.  i created profile fields like:

```
currentjobtitle1
currentjobtitle2
currentjobtitle3
pastjobtitle1
pastjobtitle2
pastjobtitle3
```

I'm a newb in every way, so i tried to code this more efficiently than normal and have become very confused.  I'm sure my code is wrong in more ways than one, but if i can just get it to work:

```
pnum=0
cnum=0
for x in clean_work_obj[:]:
    if x['end_date']:
        var='past'
        count=pnum+1
    else:
        var='current'
        count=cnum+1
    if count>3:
        break
    else:
        SarProfile.var+'jobtitle'+str(count)= x['position']['name']
```

clean_work_obj is the dict i received thru the social network api.

I had expected it to write out: SarProfile.pastjobtitle1 or SarProfile.currentjobtitle3, for example, and populate that field with the "position / name" data.  it breaks because there is no field called "var" in SarProfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setattr(SarProfile, '%sjobtitle%d' % (var, count), x['position']['name'])
```

But you probably want to create an instance of `SarProfile` first, and use that instead.

Comment: The good thing about being clueless is the solution arrives quickly and is usually easy to implement. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: The worst is when you get someone that thinks they know what they're doing but is [going about it the wrong way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).